# Accept both slice and Vec in Rust enum/struct

Tags: vector, rust, slice

I have some code similar to this

```
enum Value<'a> {
    Int(i64),
    Flt(f64),
    Vec(&'a [Value<'a>]),
}
```

and this lets me reuse some data; however, some times I want to accept heap-allocated data, so I would need something like this

```
enum Value {
   Int(i64),
   Flt(f64),
   Vec(Box<Vec<Value>>),
}
```

but now I cannot accept slices! I know I could always have both of them in the same enum, like this

```
enum Value<'a> {
   Int(i64),
   Flt(f64),
   VecSlice(&'a [Value<'a>]),
   VecBox(Box<Vec<Value<'a>>>),
}
```

but this is very ugly.

**Is there a way to have a struct or enum that accepts both slices and vectors in the same member/variant?**

I know that for functions accepting &str and String we can just set the parameters to something like `T: Into<String>` but I have not figured out how to do something like this for vectors inside data types.

Comment: `Box<Vec<Value>>` box a vector make no sense

Comment: @Stargateur well, if the vector inside the enum is unboxed, the enum size will be 32 bytes, instead of the 16 bytes it would be if boxed. This might be important in certain situations

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2813856628ca9b0f68af85fb632d862, I don't see your problem

Comment: @Stargateur you're right! I just tried returning an unboxed vector from a function, and everything works well. The issue was that I was not specifying the lifetime for the vector, hence the `Box`. Thank you :)

Comment: @Stargateur but is there a way to decrease the size to 16? It is 24 now. It's not a big deal, but I figured I would ask

Comment: I don't think slice need fat pointer and enum need some space too, note that you should not worry too much about that, code, and see after if it's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

```
enum Value<'a> {
    Int (i64),
    Flt (f64),
    Vec (Cow<'a, [Value<'a>]>),
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because of [#38962](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38962). Until that issue is fixed, you may need to re-implement a specialized version of `Cow` for `Value`:

```
enum MyCow<'a> {
    Borrowed (&'a[Value<'a>]),
    Owned (Vec<Value<'a>>)
}

impl<'a> Deref for MyCow<'a> {
    type Target = [Value<'a>];
    fn deref (&self) -> &[Value<'a>] {
        use crate::MyCow::{ Borrowed, Owned };
        match *self {
            Borrowed (borrowed) => borrowed,
            Owned (ref owned) => &owned,
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef1672a938ea1462034bd1cfb618c633)

Comment: There seems to be a [workaround](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47032#issuecomment-568784919) for using `Cow` - I haven't yet tried to apply it to this case.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the closest thing to what you want is the [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait. Notably, `Vec<T>`, `[T]`, and `[T;n]` for `n <= 32` implement `AsRef<[T]>`, as do a few other things (like an iterator over a slice). Additionally, `Box<T>` implements `AsRef<T>`, but your scenario of `Box<Vec<T>>` won't quite work here. The gets a little hairy with an enum, though. The type description doesn't quite work as:

```rust
enum Value<S>
    where S: AsRef<[Value<S>]>
{
    Int(i64),
    Flt(f64),
    Slice(S),
}
```

Because you're committed to instantiating exactly one `S` at a time, and fixing that requires using a `Box<dyn S>` to make it heterogeneous which gets really messy.

If you can refactor to make this work at the function level or create a higher level type above `Value`, you can have functions like

```
fn foo<S>(slice: S) where S: AsRef<[Value]> { }
```

Fairly easily with this construction, however. In this case if you have a `Box<Vec<Value>>` the invocation `foo(my_vec)` won't *quite* work, but can trivially be fixed with dereferencing since `Box<[T]>` implements `From<Vec<T>>`.

```rust
use std::convert::AsRef;

enum Value
{
    Int(i64),
    Flt(f64),
}

fn main() {
    use Value::*;

    let x = Box::new(vec![Int(5),Flt(22.5),Int(22)]);
    foo(*x)
}

fn foo<S>(slice: S) where S: AsRef<[Value]> {

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=734f1b477bf45fd6572ce82dbedceb4a)